# Canvas is not getting created by ReactEcharts

Tags: javascript, reactjs, echarts

i am tying to render a map in a react component using echart Library but it is not showing .
Below is the simple code for just rendering map without data.

```
render(){

    return(
        <div>
            <ReactEcharts style={{height:410}} 
              option=
              {{
               geo:{
                    show:true,
                    map:'world'
                    },

               series:[
                      {
                       type:'map',
                       map:'world'
                      }
                      ]
              }}
    ></ReactEcharts>
        </div>
    )
}
```

it should show like this 
[image: MAP Preview]
i have checked the element and found that "Canvas" element is missing from here, i don't know  why it is not getting created for map.(though it is working for other charts like scatter,barchart etc.)

```
<div class="echarts-for-react " style="height: 410px; -webkit-tap-highlight-color: transparent; user-select: none; position: relative;" _echarts_instance_="ec_1575450559839" size-sensor-id="2"><div style="position: relative; width: 257px; height: 410px; padding: 0px; margin: 0px; border-width: 0px; cursor: default;"> **CANVAS ELEMENT SHOULD BE CREATED HERE** </div><object style="display:block;position:absolute;top:0;left:0;height:100%;width:100%;overflow:hidden;pointer-events:none;z-index:-1;opacity:0" class="size-sensor-object" tabindex="-1" type="text/html" data="about:blank"></object></div>
```

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: I just ran into this. How has no one figured this out yet?